# Cannot change External Key for Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

After creating **Data Extension** I cannot change **External Key**.
Each time I change it and click "Done", refresh page and it's still the same **key**.

Comment: If you are sure about not re-using the same external key that you use on another data extension, you might create a support case: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5

Comment: I tried with unique.

Comment: Are you doing this in Email Studio or in Contact Builder? I have experienced issues when trying to change key in Contact Builder, but succeeded doing it for same DE in Email Studio

Comment: @LukasLunow Contact Builder

Comment: Try in Email Studio, and see if this solves it

Comment: @LukasLunow It solves. Looks like a workaround. Thanks. The same if add not directly from contact builder but from Contact Designer through create attribute group

Comment: Cool! Remember to mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen same "behaviour" in Contact Builder myself. Changing External Key for same Data Extension in Email Studio usually works.

**Edit September '23:**
I think this one is downprioritized (which it shouldn't be), as there is the above workaround. Please vote on [this known issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ50dAAC/attempting-to-modify-the-external-key-of-a-data-extension-in-contact-builder-does-not-save) to raise awareness with Salesforce.

Comment: And to the day three years later: this is still how it has to be done.

Comment: Just chiming in, 2 years later, this is still how it is done.